# Change Background Color With Javascript 1

Tags: javascript, css, html

How change background color with conditionally.

HTML:

```
<label class="control-label bold" id="lbstatus"></label>
```

JS:

```
if ($("#lbstatus").text() == "progress")
{
  //background color label change
}
```

Comment: `Javascript 1` ? what is javascript 1?

Comment: See the linked duplicates (or the many other similar questions). Consider using JS to add a class to the element rather than directly changing its background colour, then specify the colour in your stylesheet. @JaromandaX - You know, from back in 1996.

Comment: Brendan's baby that preceded CSS by over a year ... :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [jQuery css](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
 if ($("#lbstatus").text() === "progress")
 {
    $("#lbstatus").css("background-color", "blue");
 }
```